# Jersey resources mapping

Tags: spring, jersey

Is it possible do the following by using jersey?

```
 <mvc:resources mapping="/css/**" location="/public/css/" />
 <mvc:resources mapping="/js/**" location="/public/js/" />
 <mvc:resources mapping="/views/**" location="/public/views/" />
```

So, i need to handle /css/some.css like /public/css/some.css

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Jersey itself doesn't serve static resources, presumably you're integrating with Spring that should work already as long as you registered the dispatch servlet and you don't have a JAX-RS resource at the top level like @Path("/"), subset them to @Path("/services") for example.

Comment: Does it mean that i should have one dispatcher(Jersey) to handle /rest/* requests and another one spring mvc dispatcher that will handle / requests and static content by unsing <mvc:resources mapping... />?

Comment: Just one dispatcher to handle all requests registered to root. Make sure your JAXRS resources are discovered and don't register to root or you will only get the JAXRS resources. The static resources are given the lowest priority by the dispatcher servlet, if the Jersey resource MAY handle it, which it may if you use the @Path("/"), the dispatcher assumes that it will